# if $|S\cap \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}|\ge un$, etc. show that $\Bbb Z_{+}\subset S+T$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $S,T\subset \Bbb N$, and $0\in S$. and there exist positive real numbers $u,v$ such 
$$|S\cap \{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}|\ge un$$
$$|T\cap \{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}|\ge vn$$
for any positive integer $n$, show that: if $u+v\ge 1$, then $\Bbb Z_{+}\subset S+T$

It's very interesting problem, but I can't solve it by now.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the Borel Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг,are you mean this lemma:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Cantelli_lemma?

Comment: Yes, I think I mean this lemma. Read it carefully, see if you can use it.

Comment: Now.I have read this lemma,and can't use this solve this problem.can you explain?

Comment: The answer below is just a disguised use of the Borel Cantelli Lemma. In other words, it's just in  a different measure space.

Answer (score 1):

Using $n=1$ we see $1\in S,T$, so at least $0+1,1+1\in S+T$.
To show that $m\in S+T$, it suffices to have any $k$ with $1\le k\le m-1$ to have $k\in S$ and $m-k\in T$.
If this fails, we know that $$|S\cap\{1,\ldots,m-1\}|+|T\cap\{1,\ldots,m-1\}|\le
m-1.$$ This is only possible if the given bounds are sharp, i.e., 
$$ |S\cap\{1,\ldots,m-1\}|=u(m-1),\quad |T\cap\{1,\ldots,m-1\}|=v(m-1), \quad u+v=1.$$
As $v>0$, this implies 
$$ |T\cap\{1,\ldots,m\}|\ge vm>v(m-1)=|T\cap\{1,\ldots,m-1\}|$$
so that $m\in T$ and so $m=0+m\in S+T$.

Comment: why $|S\bigcap \{1,2,\cdots,m-1\}|+|T\bigcap\{1,2,\cdots,m-1\}|\le m-1?$

Comment: @inequality Each of the $m-1$ pairs $(a,b)$ with $a+b=m-1$ can have $a\in S$ or $b\in T$, but not both (and all elements between $1$ and $m-1$ (incl.) of $S$ and $T$ are obtained this way).